# Android set True or False - Clear on App Exit

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want a notification to pop up when an app opens.  But once User dismisses, I don't want it to come back again, even if they go back to the same activity.  But when the app exits, and they come back later, I want same dialog notification to pop up (prompting user to login).

So basically...

```
boolean b = true;

if (b == true) {
     // show dialog
     b = false;
}
```

I simply want var b to save state but clear on exit.

Comment: android has no concept of "app exit", only the android lifecycle, so you'll have to be more specific about the behavior you want.

Comment: yes I know that, bad wording... onDestroy I guess?

Comment: i doubt that's what you want. can you describe the behavior? e.g., do you mean when the user leaves your app visually like returns to the home screen, and then returns to your app, the state should be reset?

Comment: yes.  I suppose I can just do it with the application class.  Even if it is set forever thats ok.

Comment: if you truly want forever, use a preference. otherwise, it's non-deterministic. the user will see the message again, sometime, but it's completely unpredictable when they will see it. it might be 5 minutes, it might be a week. having a dialog with a "don't show me this again" check box is a pretty standard way to accomplish this.

Comment: For this app, I don't mind if it is slightly unpredictable, as long as it doesn't annoy the user by popping up EACH TIME the Activity starts.  If it comes back for a periodic, random reminder to "hey, why don't you create an account?"  that works by me.  It's sort of like those apps that randomly ask you to rate it.

Comment: you mean those terribly annoying apps that keep asking you to rate them? automatic uninstall.

Comment: First off that is every big name app. Secondly this is nothing like that. Just a comparison of concept.

Comment: don't take my word for it, check with your local UX authority.

Comment: Hey, I agree with you.  I'm on your side here.  (Though I don't uninstall great apps (such as Titanium Backup) every time I am asked to rate their app.)  But you don't understand the context of what I'm doing.  It's an app that is restrictive if you are not logged in.  (But in order for new users to get a preview of what the app is, they can navigate through it without being logged in).  So a reminder to login when app is first open is appropriate here.  Once logged in, the app remembers state and they won't see this again.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPuIJQSwuHg&feature=relmfu. take a look at about 12:30 in where they start ranting on apps that pop up dialogs. they specifically mention apps that pop up dialogs asking the user to rate the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure there's a point to using sharedpreference if you don't want the value to persist across your app being closed, as that's kind of the point of them.

Perhaps just using a boolean in your Application class would be better? It will be persistent until the app is completely shutdown.

Comment: I do have an application class to handle this. I will try that!

Comment: the application class will theoretically live forever. the user could run the app weeks later and the state in the app class will still be set.

Answer (score 1):

android has no concept of "app exit", only the android lifecycle, so you'll have to be more specific about the behavior you want. for example, do you mean whenever the user causes any activity in your app to be paused and no activity in your app to be resumed?

if you only have one activity, then you can just keep a state variable in the activity setting it to false when paused and true when resumed.

if you have >1 activity, keeping track of when none of your activities are in the foreground any longer is painful. for example, if you set foreground=false whenever an activity pauses, and foreground=true whenever it's resumed, and then check a time tolerance. e.g., if the time between pause and resume is greater than some threshold, assume you are coming back from the background.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use SharedPrefs unless they logout out of app with a button or some other listener, you can't be sure to change it. You can put it in onDestroy() to reset the variable or onPause() even better if you want to make sure it gets reset